# MySql - JSON data not showing in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm trying to create a drop down list from a MySql.

The php is successfully fetching the data from the MySql. But my problem is the data is not showing on the drop down list in my HTML page?

json_mysql_data2.php

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
require_once("con.php");
$i=0;
$jsonData = array();
foreach ($conn_db->query("SELECT customerID FROM customers WHERE furniture='33' ") as $result){
        $i++;
        $jsonData["article".$i]=$result['customerID'];
    }
echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

myJS.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ddlist = document.getElementById("ddlist");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("GET", "json_mysql_data2.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var d = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            for(var o in d){
                if(d[o].title){
                    ddlist.innerHTML += '</option><option value='+d[o].title+'</option>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    hr.send("null");
    ddlist.innerHTML = "Loading Customer ID....";
});
```

html

```
<script src="myJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dlist">
        Customer ID: 
        <select id='EmpLst' name="dwlist" onchange='document.getElementById("val1").value = this.value;'><option value="">SELECT STUDENT ID</option>
        <div id="ddlist"></div>
        </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why do you add an extra `</option>` before each `<option>`?

Comment: There are certain mistakes like extra </option> also in the dom element you are adding this in a div which is in a select, that's a bad practice although.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `innerHTML` is wrong. You have an extra `</option>` at the beginning, you're missing the closing `>` of the `<option>`. You also don't have any text in the option, so the menu items will all be blank.

You also should be appending to the `<select>` instead of a `<div>`.

```
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var d = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
        var empList = document.getElementById("EmpList");
        for(var o in d){
            if(d[o].title){
                empList.innerHTML += '<option value="'+d[o].title+'">'+d[o].title+'</option>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. That did not solve the problem. I have doubts if the `<div id="ddlist"></div>` will actually work inside `<select id='EmpLst' name.....`

Comment: Possibly true. Why don't you append to the `<select>` instead of the `<div>`?

Comment: I have thought about that, but I'm not sure how to get "SELECT STUDENT ID" as the 1st item and also to get `onchange='document.getElementById("val1").value = this.value;'><option value="">`

Comment: Since you're concatenating to the inner HTML, all that stuff will be left there.

Answer (score 0):

```
ddlist.innerHTML += '</option><option value='+d[o].title+'</option>';
```

should be

```
ddlist.innerHTML += '<option value="'+d[o].title+'">'+d[o].title+'</option>';
```